# how to hide state param from url in angularjs with asp.net MVC5?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
.state('Wizard', {
 url: '/Wizard/:Email',
 templateUrl: '/Common/_Wizard',
 controller: 'Common_Wizard',
```

}

We are seeing email address in our url like

localhost:15646/Home/Index#/Wizard/sda@adal.com/Loan/Loan

sda@adal.com this is an email address.and this email address is used in different controller and views.
how we can hide this and access on other controller and views.
we dont want to use any local storage or service.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You could create service factory class:

```
angular.module('YourApp').factory('UserContext', function() {
   this.getUserEmail = function() {...}
});
```

to encapsulate user (email,...) data and inject it in every controller:

```
angular.module('YourApp').controller('FooBar', function($scope, UserContext) { 
   $scope.email = UserContext.getUserEmail();
});
```

You could also just put the data into the $rootScope, but this is for sure not the best idea.